# Drawing picture of the state of stack

Tags: stack

The question tells us to draw a picture of the stack at the specified point of the following code:

```
int rtn(int *&r) {
    int i = 7, *pr = r;
    r = &i;
    // <--- STATE OF STACK AT THIS POINT
}
int main() {
    int i = 3; *pi = &i;
    rtn(pi);
}
```

The answer turns out to be the following:

```
     ,----------,  
     | r :  ----+--------,  
 rtn | i : 7  <-+-’<--,  |  
     | pr : ----+--,  |  |  
     }----------{  |  |  |  
     | i : 3    |<-’  |  |  
main | pi : ----+-----’<-’  
     ‘----------’
```

I'm having a hard time interpretting this particular picture of the stack.
Can anyone give me a general idea of how to draw a picture of the stack and what each part of that diagram is representing?
Thank you!